# Certain ProgressBar styles not shown on Nexus 5 Android 5.0.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-progressbar

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a Nexus 5 running `Android 5.0.1` that doesn't display the `ProgressBar`, obviously because of the style. When I set the style for example to

```
 style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
```

or

```
 style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Large"
```

it is shown. I have an identical Nexus 5 also running `Android 5.0.1` which displays all the `ProgressBar`s fine. 
Enabling the 'draw layout borders' option in the developers options, it shows that the `ProgressBar` is included in the layout, it is simply not shown.

This seems very strange, any idea on what could be going on here?

[image]

Comment: i have a nexus 4 running android 5.0.1 and it's working fine.. perhaps your ota update is borked? try reflashing the device using factory images?

Comment: So which styles DON'T work?

Comment: Are there any fixes for this? Incredibly frustrating...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was having the same issue but was because the developer phone have animations scales to 0 (all 3).

Enable all the animations on the device and maybe you will be able to see the progress bar, so for normal people that will have animations enabled the progress bar will appear fine.

Comment: Thanks .. Forgot to reset animations in "Developer options" after espresso tests :)

Comment: I also had to kill and restart the app, before the progress bar started to show up.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it looks as if the issue is with build LRX22G:

```
Nexus 7 using Build LRX22G (android-5.0.2_r1) - progress bar not shown

Nexus 5 using Build LRX22C (android-5.0.1_r1) - progress bar shown
```

See https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html

It's probably also related with https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77865

Not being able to wait for a fix, what I've decided to do is to force the Holo progress bar to be used in my Material theme. This is how it was achieved - it may be of some use to you in the meantime:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Build LRX22G (5.0.2 Nexus 7) fails to display progress bar so we'll use Holo instead of Material -->
    <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567235/certain-progressbar-styles-not-shown-on-nexus-5-android-5-0-1 -->
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleSmall">@style/MaterialProgressBarFix.Small</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/MaterialProgressBarFix</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleLarge">@style/MaterialProgressBarFix.Large</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialProgressBarFix.Small" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Small" />
<style name="MaterialProgressBarFix"       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar" />
<style name="MaterialProgressBarFix.Large" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Large" />
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting the style to the following instead you should be able to debug this issue

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
```

Comment: Good idea. Oddly enough, this isn't displayed either.

Comment: I guess that means it is not picking the theme

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem -  using style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge is fine on 5.0.1 Nexus 5 but is invisible on my 2012 Nexus 7 5.0.2